# How to convert JSON date to UTC format

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

After reviewing the comments I have decided to clarify my question to make things much more clearer about exactly what the issue is and what I am trying to do.

I am attempting to take an Angular Bootstrap form, which is data bound to the `Orders` model on the scope and wish to convert this object into `x-www-urlencoded` format e.g. `OrderRef=101121&OrderDate=2015-02-02T17:40:00.111Z&Address=140%20Acacia%20Street` so that I can pass it an `$http.post(..)` method.

I have found an example on the Internet where I could convert my `Order` object into `x-www-urlencoded` form.  This almost works, but the date properties in the object are not being formatted as UTC.

I have a RESTful API that expects all dates to be passed as UTC formatted dates and the `POST` fails with an error.

When I convert my object using the following code as an example:

```
var order = {
    OrderRef: '101121',
    OrderDate: new Date('02/02/2015'),
    Address: '140 Acacia Street'
}

var data = jQuery.param(order);
```

I am getting `Mon+Mar+02+2015+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B0000+(GMT+Standard+Time)` for the OrderDate property which isn't what I wanted.

If I send this converted object to my RESTful API it errors because it doesn't understand that particular date format.

Is there a built-in JavaScript function that correctly converts an object with `Date` properties into UTC format?

This is the Bootstrap UI `<input>` element I am trying to bind to the `OrderDate` property.

It displays the date correctly only when using `new Date('02/02/2015')` on the property.  It will not work if I did this `OrderDate: '02/02/2015' as the input element will not show the date at all.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputOrderRef3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order Ref</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrderRef3" placeholder="Order Ref" ng-model="order.OrderRef" maxlength="6" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Twitter Bootstrap v3.3.2 with AngularJS v1.3.9 and jQuery 2.1.3.

Comment: I don't see any JSON here, and don't know what you mean by "JSON dates". If you want to control output format of the date, use the various methods available to the Date object.  Your example also seems trivial, in that if you know the date (in this case `02/02/2015`) why not just write it to `OrderDate` directly in the format you want?

Comment: json doesn't have dates. json is just a text-encoding of a javascript data structure. if you want a UTC date in your json, then you'd have to ensure that whatever data structure you're encoding has a UTC-formatted string to begin with.

Comment: You're wording your question wrong, but if I understand what you are attempting to do, you're looking for something like `date.toUTCString()` [reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

Comment: @HowardRenollet: I have tried that but since I'm using Bootstrap UI the input field won't accept any dates unless the date is created using the Date(...) object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue at one point I tried momentjs.

Try this http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: I have updated my question to clarify things a bit more as I do not think `momentjs` will actually solve my problem, unless I'm mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem by doing it the hard way and creating an `encode` function that will generate the url-encoded string manually.

```
var order = {
    OrderRef: '100101',
    OrderDate: new Date('02/02/2015'),
    CustomerName: 'ACME Installations Ltd',
    Value: 525.00,
    encode: function () {
        return "OrderRef=" + encodeURIComponent(this.OrderRef) + "&OrderDate=" + encodeURIComponent(this.OrderDate.toUTCString()) +
            "&CustomerName=" + encodeURIComponent(this.CustomerName) +  "&Value=" + encodeURIComponent(this.Value) +
            "&Invoice=0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class

```
 public class UTCDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public UTCDateTimeConverter()
    {
        base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

Now convert as follows

```
    [JsonProperty("label")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UTCDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime label { get; set; }
```